# Start Lightbox on page load Cerabox + Mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools, lightbox

I have a [Cerabox lightbox](http://cerabox.net/) setup and working just fine. But I'd love to see it execute on page load without a visitor clicking on the link. Anybody got kung-fu mootools skills that can help?

Here's the code:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
//modal
$$('a.video').cerabox({
width: 560,
height: 345,
displayOverlay: false
});

<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/h8WiyX21A1c?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" class="video youtube"><img src="http://thumbnail.jpg" alt="video thumbnail"><div class="btn-play"><p>&gt;</p></div></a>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not the best written plugin as api, also not great that it extends Element / Elements prototypes when it can be a getter. the constructor is nearly 100 lines... This is *not* how Classes are meant to be written. Anyway, this is for the author to decide and maintain...

https://github.com/ceramedia/CeraBox/blob/master/cerabox.js#L134-L143

This part shows a very NON-DRY element binding without a simple abstraction like `this.open`.

You do, however, have the option to fire the event handler like so:

```
document.getElement('a.video').fireEvent('click'); // after cerabox init.
```

one thing: you do `$$('a.video').cerabox()` - this is a collection. you can only open 1 modal at a time so... if you mean it to be a single element binding, it's just `node.getElement(selector)` as in my example.

alternatively, you can do this:

```
var cb = el.retrieve('cerabox'); // some el from $$('a.video')
// gets actual class instance exposed through element storage

if (cb._itemClick(event)) {
    cb.currentItem = cb.collection.indexOf(cb);
    cb.showInline(); // or whatever method is appropriate
}
```

the problem is he has a dependence on the index in the elements collection in a private function - hence `.indexOf` to get it through an external puncture... have fun

Comment: That line works perfectly. I had trouble finding any options for auto-firing any of the functions included with the plugin. Thanks for your help.